# Ruby map on hash key

Tags: ruby

I always end up writing the following code in order to obtain an array of values for a certain key:

```
hash.map{ |h| h['key'] || "default" }
```

Does anyone know a cleaner way of writing the same code?

Something like:

```
hash.map_keys(&:key, 'default')
```

Comment: This makes no sense. Can you give us sample inputs and outputs? The line of code you've provided doesn't really accomplish anything sensible.

Comment: I just realized myself that it makes no sense. What I mean is the following:

I have an array of hashes: `[{email: 'a'}, {email: 'b'}]` from which I would like to obtain: `['a', 'b']`

Comment: Please don't clarify in comments, edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: Why would you want to do `map_keys(&:key)`? `map_keys("key")` would make more sense.

Comment: @meagar I think you misinterpreted the question. Your answer seem to miss the point, and it is not a duplicate of the question you linked. The OP already knows how to do it (the OP's code is the same as the accepted answer to the question you linked). The OP is looking for a shorthand for that.

Comment: @sawa It's a difference between "how do I do X" and "what's the best way to do X". The answer is the same.

Comment: @meagar The OP is particularly looking for a way to do it without explicitly writing a block.

Comment: @user3866597 `hash.map_keys(&:key, 'default')` is invalid. A block has come after the arguments. Therefore, it is impossible to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `hash.keys` to get the hash keys.

To get the the values from an array of hashes for a key you can use [fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) if you need to set a default.

Comment: This seems to be answering a different question than the one that was asked

Answer (score 0):

If you want the values, you're after `hash.values`.